# Servlet Filter : how to catch HTTP error

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, httpresponse, servlet-filters, http-status-code-401

Is there a way to catch HTTP error with a servlet Filter ? Are HTTP errors stored in the filter SevletResponse ?
My goal is to catch some authentication errors (401) to redirect user to a spare authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`getStatus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getStatus%28%29) method of the `HttpServletResponse`. That contains the server response, eg. 401/`SC_UNAUTHORIZED`.

Comment: There are 2 important notes which shouldn't be left unnoticed: 1) This method is introduced in Servlet 3.0, thus won't compile/work in older versions. 2) This approach won't work when container managed authentication is used which bypasses all filters.

Comment: Ok your second point is right : I'm using jboss_negotiation authentification so the filter doens't catch 401 error. Any idea to get same result in that case ?